# MySQL 8 leap second and daylight saving time (DST) time time_zone_name table

Tags: mysql, timezone, mysql-8.0, leap-second

When I issue this statement:

```
SELECT * FROM mysql.time_zone_name WHERE `name` like '%london%';
```

I get this list:

```
+---------------------+--------------+
| Name                | Time_zone_id |
+---------------------+--------------+
| Europe/London       |          451 |
| posix/Europe/London |         1059 |
| right/Europe/London |         1667 |
+---------------------+--------------+
```

But there is no information about support of DST, leap seconds.
What is the table name I could select that information from?

If there is no table that has that information, can you please link some reliable source of that information?

I could not find that information in the documentation of MySQL 8. The only thing I found was: [community package of timezones](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/timezones.html)
Reading it leads me into conclusion that `posix/` timezones does not have leap second results, and probably `right/` means it may return `right` in terms of `exact` time so potentially having a leap second. But I'm uncertain about my conclusion also I don't know if usnig the `Europe/London` may give result with leap second or not and if all three of them support DST.

I'm using Linux Debian for the MySQL server and client.

Comment: Most OSes do not support leap seconds. I haven't paid too much attention, but I would assume they are not relevant for transaction processing. OSes then to spread them evenly during the day to ensure each day has always 86400 seconds. Just my two cents.

Comment: Since you are on linux, which comes with its own timezones database, you should check debian's documentation on the timezones as opposed to mysql's.

Comment: Did a bit of research, you need to dig into the tz database documentation to find out what you are after: https://data.iana.org/time-zones/tz-link.html